# Checking to see if a bmp file exists in C++

Tags: c++, c, windows

I create a file, a bmp file, and store it in a certain directory. What I want to check is that it is there after (so whether the creation was successful). I have

```
FILE *pfile;
pfile = fopen("C:\Users\me\Test-Outputs\Capture Output\test.bmp", "r");

if(pfile != NULL)
    worked!
else 
    didnt work!!
```

But it's not working. It says the file does not exist even though it does. Anyone know where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Doesn't look like valid C to me.

Comment: @filmor: If the OP clearly wrote C++ in the title, why would you remove that tag?  Just because a piece of code happens to also be valid C (sans the `worked!` and `didnt work!!` part), does not make it not C++.

Comment: Well, it doesn't have anything to do with C++ (esp the use of FILE indicates that), but you're right, removing the tag wasn't smart. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 6):

Use double backslashes. The single backslash is an escape char in C and C-like languages.

Comment: Or use single forward-slashes, which is more readable, and more portable.

Comment: Can you believe ive done that in several other places in this code. Think this thing is just starting to get to me now. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

You have to escape the backslashes with another backslash. Try

```
pfile = fopen("C:\\Users\\me\\Test-Outputs\\Capture Output\\test.bmp", "r");
```

Using forward slashes should also work.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the `fopen` line with:

```
pfile = fopen("C:\\Users\\me\\Test-Outputs\\Capture Output\\test.bmp", "r");
```

Answer (score 0):

as filmor said, use the following:

```
pfile = fopen("C:\\Users\\me\\Test-Outputs\\Capture Output\\test.bmp", "r");
```

Answer (score -1):

I think that the better way to do that is use the "access" function.

```
#include <unistd.h>
int access(const char *pathname, int mode);
```

It returns zero on success.