# batch file start but commands doesn't run when started in c

Tags: c, windows, batch-file, cmd

I have made a batch file. When I double-click the batch-file in the windows explorer it runs as expected. No problems occurs. I use windows 7.

But when I start the batch-file in C with the `system` command only the cmd-window appears but it runs no commands and closed the window directly.

The command in C is: `system("D:\Projects\12-Test\Run-1\Start-LSDYNA.bat");`

How I can start the batch-file successfully in C?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Checking to see if a bmp file exists in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8746000/checking-to-see-if-a-bmp-file-exists-in-c)

Comment: Can you give a example

Comment: For your kind reference: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character#Programming_and_data_formats

Answer (score 2):

Use either

```
system("D:\\Projects\\12-Test\\Run-1\\Start-LSDYNA.bat");
```

or

```
system("D:/Projects/12-Test/Run-1/Start-LSDYNA.bat");
```

`\` has a special meaning in strings. For e.g `'\n'` or `'\t'`. So you need to escape it with another `\`. Or use `/` which also works.

Comment: Both possibilities don't work. Are there other ideas?

Comment: @user2441767 - how do you know it didn't work? Do one thing. Edit the batch file - add this as the first line - `echo Hello > %TEMP%\ran.txt`. After running your C program, check the %TEMP% directory if a file called ran.txt has been created.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. But when I start the batch file manually ran.txt is correctly generated. When I start it in C the cmd-window appears and is closed directly, without running the command.

Comment: echo on
c:
cd C:\Program Files\LSTC\LS-PrePost\4.1-X64
start /min lsprepost
pause

Comment: echo on
c:
cd C:\Program Files\LSTC\LS-PrePost\4.1-X64
start /min lsprepost
pause

Comment: echo onc:
cd C:\Program Files\LSTC\LS-PrePost\4.1-X64
start /min lsprepost
pause

Comment: The coomands per line: 1. echo on 2. c: 3. cd C:\Program Files\LSTC\LS-PrePost\4.1-X64 4. start /min lsprepost 5. pause

Comment: @user2441767 - delete ran.txt and run your C Program & see if ran.txt is generated or not

Comment: ran.txt is not generated when I run teh batch-file in C